# Typeahead wont show results but the php/mysql is working

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I'm trying to implement a autocomplete form, using data form a MySQL database.

This is my HTML:

```
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u' crossorigin='anonymous'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='jQuery/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css'>
<script src='jQuery/jQuery.js'></script>
<script src='jQuery/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js'></script>

<style>.typeahead, ...
//same as every other example
</style>

    <script src='typeahead/typeahead.js'></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 

$('#sdis').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
 limit: 12,
 async: true,
 source: function (query, processSync, processAsync) {
  processSync(['This suggestion appears immediately', 'This one too']);
  return $.ajax({
   url: 'sdis.php', 
   type: 'GET',
   data: {query: query},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (json) {
     // in this example, json is simply an array of strings
     return processAsync(json);
     }
   });
  }
 });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='text' class='form-control typeahead' id='test-field' placeholder='Contact'/>
</body>
```

I'm using typeahead.js 0.11.1 and all includes are working.

When a run sdis.php?query=word

I get the following list:

```
["Word","Wordpress"]
```

But when I type it in the input nothing happens. So, that means that the php part is working just fine and returning JSON encoded results (that why I didn't post it here), but somehow the typeahead is not getting the results as expected. I sent the JSON header as well in the php part. Any help/suggestion is welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are you using your `substringMatcher` function?

Comment: It looks I'm not. To be honest, i don't even know why it is necessary. Would typeahead be able to understand the JSON returned by sdis.php without it?